# firestore array-contains query not working in golang

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to query a firestore array and I am using the golang library.  Unfortunately when I run my query i Get the "invalid operator "array-contains" error

Not sure why I am getting this as I am running my query exactly as shown (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/f8a3a6ed786b9fd96a5e92c2ef5fb849ec7896a9/firestore/firestore_snippets/query.go#L255)

In case it matters my structure is..

`rootLevel[].secondLevel[].attribute`

My Code:

```
    query := collection.Query
    query = query.Where("AllAccessTokens.polar.PartnerGUID", "array-contains", "aasdfasdf")
    iter := query.Documents(ctx)
    results, resultError := iter.GetAll()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate it.   I think that I figured it out.  Sort of stupid but my array-contains was on a complex object.  Not an array of strings.  Once I changed my model then it worked perfectly.   Thank you!